# Context In JavaScript behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, canvas

Ok, so I'm building a flappy bird clone for a class, the game is being built in HTML using Canvas and Javascript. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and I've hit a bit of a snag. I have a working game, but it is of fixed window size and I would like to scale the game as the user scales their window.

My working fixed scale game is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: black;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  position: relative; left:210px;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #EE0000;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">

<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var scoreObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var myHighScore;
var spacePressed;
var jumpSound;
var deathSound;
var score = 0;

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "black", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.10;
    myGamePiece.life = 1;
    myScore = new component("12px", "Verdana", "black", 500, 25, "text");
    myMessage = new component("12px", "Verdana", "black", 175, 235, "text");
    jumpSound = new sound("bark.mp3");
    deathSound = new sound("bonk.mp3");
    myGameArea.start();
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32){
        spacePressed = true;
    }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32){
        spacePressed = false;
    }
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
    this.canvas.style = "border:3px solid black;"
        this.canvas.width = 600;
        this.canvas.height = 470;
        this.canvas.offsetTop = 50;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        updateGameArea();
        },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;    
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        if(spacePressed)
        {
            accelerate(-.4)
            jumpSound.play();
        }
        if(!spacePressed)
        {
            accelerate(.1)
        }
        var ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type === "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    }
    
    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var bottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        var top = 0
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if(this.y > bottom || mytop < top){
            return true;
        }
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {
    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            if (myGamePiece.life == 1) {
                myGamePiece.life = 0;
                deathSound.play();
                myMessage.text="You crashed! Press SPACE to try again!"
                myMessage.update();
            }
            if (spacePressed) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            return;
        } 
    }

    for (i = 0; i < scoreObstacles.length; i++) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(scoreObstacles[i])) {
          score++;
        }
    }
    
    
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo === 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 45;
        maxHeight = 225;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 90;
        maxGap = 150;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(70, height, "yellow", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(70, x - height - gap, "yellow", x, height + gap));
        scoreObstacles.push(new component(70, gap, "#ffffff00", x, height));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1.5;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    for(i = 0; i, i <scoreObstacles.length; i++){
      scoreObstacles[i].x += -1.5;
      scoreObstacles[i].update();
   }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + Math.round(score/67);
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }    
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 === 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    if (!myGameArea.interval) {myGameArea.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);}

    myGamePiece.gravity = n;
}
</script>
<br>

<p style = "font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;">
  Press <b>SPACE</b> to jump!  Avoid the obstacles and don't go out of bounds!</p>

<button class="button button1" onClick="window.location='StartGame.html';">Back</button>
<button class="button button1" onClick="window.location.reload();">Restart</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and my game the version that I am attempting to scale is this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<style>
    #canvas {
        left: 100%;
        right: 100%;
        border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
        background-color: #f1f1f1
    }

    #gameArea {
        position: absolute;
        border:1px solid #c15656;
        left: 50%;
        right: 50%;
    }

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.4s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #FFFFE0;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: black;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  position: relative; left:210px;
}

.button1:hover {
  background-color: #EE0000;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
    <div id = "gameArea">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        <script>

var myGamePiece;
var myObstacles = [];
var scoreObstacles = [];
var myScore;
var myHighScore;
var spacePressed;
var jumpSound;
var deathSound;
var score = 0;


function startGame() {

    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "black", 10, 120);
    myGamePiece.gravity = 0.10;
    myGamePiece.life = 1;
    myScore = new component("12px", "Verdana", "black", 500, 25, "text");
    myMessage = new component("12px", "Verdana", "black", 175, 235, "text");
    jumpSound = new sound("bark.mp3");
    deathSound = new sound("bonk.mp3");
    myGameArea.start();
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32){
        spacePressed = true;
    }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 32){
        spacePressed = false;
    }
}





var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.getElementById("canvas"),
    gameArea: document.getElementById("gameArea"),
    ctx : this.canvas.getContext("2d"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.style = "border:3px solid black;";
        this.resize();
        this.context = this.ctx;
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.frameNo = 0;
        updateGameArea();
    },
    resize : function ()
    {
        this.context = this.ctx;
        var widthToHeight = 600 / 470;
        var newWidth = window.innerWidth - window.innerWidth * .25;
        var newHeight = window.innerHeight - window.innerHeight * .25;
        var newWidthToHeight = newWidth / newHeight;

        //keeps the game's aspect ratio
        if (newWidthToHeight > widthToHeight) {
            newWidth = newHeight * widthToHeight;
            this.gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
            this.gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
        } else {
            newHeight = newWidth / widthToHeight;
            this.gameArea.style.width = newWidth + 'px';
            this.gameArea.style.height = newHeight + 'px';
        }
        //keeps the gameArea in the center of the screen when resizing
        this.gameArea.style.marginLeft = (-newWidth / 2) + 'px';

        this.canvas.width = newWidth;
        this.canvas.height = newHeight;


        var scaleFactorX = this.canvas.width/600
        var scaleFactorY = this.canvas.height/470

        this.ctx.scale(scaleFactorX, scaleFactorY);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('resize', myGameArea.resize, false);
window.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', myGameArea.resize, false)
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', myGameArea.resize, false);

function component(width, height, color, x, y, type) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = 0;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.gravity = 0;
    this.gravitySpeed = 0;
    this.update = function() {
        if(spacePressed)
        {
            accelerate(-.4)
            jumpSound.play();
        }
        if(!spacePressed)
        {
            accelerate(.1)
        }
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        if (this.type === "text") {
            ctx.font = this.width + " " + this.height;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillText(this.text, this.x, this.y);
        } else {
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        }
    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.gravitySpeed += this.gravity;
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY + this.gravitySpeed;
    }

    this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
        var bottom = myGameArea.canvas.height - this.height;
        var top = 0
        var myleft = this.x;
        var myright = this.x + (this.width);
        var mytop = this.y;
        var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
        var otherleft = otherobj.x;
        var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
        var othertop = otherobj.y;
        var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
        var crash = true;
        if(this.y > bottom || mytop < top){
            return true;
        }
        if ((mybottom < othertop) || (mytop > otherbottom) || (myright < otherleft) || (myleft > otherright)) {
            crash = false;
        }
        return crash;
    }
}

function updateGameArea() {

    var x, height, gap, minHeight, maxHeight, minGap, maxGap;
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
            if (myGamePiece.life == 1) {
                myGamePiece.life = 0;
                deathSound.play();
                myMessage.text="You crashed! Press SPACE to try again!"
                myMessage.update();
            }
            if (spacePressed) {
                window.location.reload();
            }
            return;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < scoreObstacles.length; i++) {
        if (myGamePiece.crashWith(scoreObstacles[i])) {
            score++;
        }
    }


    myGameArea.clear();
    myGameArea.frameNo += 1;
    if (myGameArea.frameNo === 1 || everyinterval(150)) {
        x = myGameArea.canvas.width;
        minHeight = 45;
        maxHeight = 225;
        height = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxHeight-minHeight+1)+minHeight);
        minGap = 90;
        maxGap = 150;
        gap = Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxGap-minGap+1)+minGap);
        myObstacles.push(new component(70, height, "yellow", x, 0));
        myObstacles.push(new component(70, x - height - gap, "yellow", x, height + gap));
        scoreObstacles.push(new component(70, gap, "#ffffff00", x, height));
    }
    for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
        myObstacles[i].x += -1.5;
        myObstacles[i].update();
    }
    for(i = 0; i, i <scoreObstacles.length; i++){
        scoreObstacles[i].x += -1.5;
        scoreObstacles[i].update();
    }
    myScore.text="SCORE: " + Math.round(score/67);
    myScore.update();
    myGamePiece.newPos();
    myGamePiece.update();
}

function sound(src) {
    this.sound = document.createElement("audio");
    this.sound.src = src;
    this.sound.setAttribute("preload", "auto");
    this.sound.setAttribute("controls", "none");
    this.sound.style.display = "none";
    document.body.appendChild(this.sound);
    this.play = function(){
        this.sound.play();
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        this.sound.pause();
    }
}

function everyinterval(n) {
    if ((myGameArea.frameNo / n) % 1 === 0) {return true;}
    return false;
}

function accelerate(n) {
    if (!myGameArea.interval) {
        myGameArea.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    }

    myGamePiece.gravity = n;


}
        </script>

<br>

<p style = "font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-style:normal;">
  Press <b>SPACE</b> to jump!  Avoid the obstacles and don't go out of bounds!</p>

<button class="button button1" onClick="window.location='StartGame.html';">Back</button>
<button class="button button1" onClick="window.location.reload();">Restart</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem that I'm finding with this code is line 120, or my definition of CTX in myGameArea, the game will not display without the definition, but it stops the canvas from sitting inside the gameArea when I insert it. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your game doesn't display when you remove your `ctx` declaration because other parts of your code reference the `ctx` property and when it isn't there anymore, the JavaScript interpreter will throw an error and stop executing your script.
Check the log console of your browser for more information.

As for what is moving your `<canvas id="canvas">` outside of `<div id="gameArea">`, that's the following line inside `myGameArea.start()`

```
document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

This line of code tells the browser to navigate to the `<body>` tag of your page and insert `this.canvas` before `document.body.childNodes[0]`, which is the first child of the `<body>` tag, which just so happens to be `<div id="gameArea">`.

So that line is taking `<canvas id="canvas">` and moving it before `<div id="gameArea">`.

You could remove that line and your canvas will snuggly stay inside your game area div.

As an extra for your school project I would suggest finding a way to *prevent* the *default* behaviour when pressing the space bar on a website.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response that makes a lot of sense! I'll look into stopping the spacebar scroll.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is this line:

```
document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
```

Because the canvas is already in the gameArea (hardcoded in the html) and you don't need to insert it anymore. When you delete it the game works and is responsive.